# jQuery auto loading records generate same record set when scrolling, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added jQuery data auto loading when page scroll down. It is working nicely. but sometime it is generated same record set again. This is the code is used, and I check the issue, **Then I got sometimes track_load variable not increment.**

eg:
when page load first time: **track_load = 0**
when scroll down: **track_load should be = 1**, 
but sometime **it gives 0**

**someone please explain how to fix this issue, thank you.....**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

    $('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group

    $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-200)  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
        {

            if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
            {
                loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
                $.post('autoload_process.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                    $("#results").append(data); //append received data into the element

                    //hide loading image
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                    track_load++; //loaded group increment
                    loading = false; 

                }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                    loading = false;

                });

            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'it gives 0'? How did you check that?

Comment: @Diego I checked it in autoload_process.php page. this script post {'group_no': track_load} data to php script. I echo that group_no. then I saw when scrolling (first scroll) return 0 agian.

Comment: @user3099298 Check out the solution that I posted it should do the trick, let me know if it works out for you

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that its loading track 0 twice, you call the load function initially and pass in as a call back to increment, but if you reach the bottom of the page before you finish loading your going to load the same data twice.

Also try doing something like this for your load when you plug into the scroll even it hits so many times it can slow the client computer down you should just set a timeout instead

**Edit this should work with your code and not cause the client to hit too many events**

```
var scrollListener = function () {
    executeScrollIfinBounds();
    $(window).one("scroll", function () { //unbinds itself every time it fires
       executeScrollIfinBounds();
       setTimeout(scrollListener, 200); //rebinds itself after 200ms
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

   $('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;
        //initialize scroll listener
        scrollListener();
    }); //load first group


});


function executeScrollIfinBounds()
{
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
     if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
        {
            loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
            $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

            //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
            $.post('autoload_process.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                $("#results").append(data); //append received data into the element

                //hide loading image
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                track_load++; //loaded group increment
                loading = false; 

            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                loading = false;

            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked this code, but it didn't work, this code is not working when page scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.. what i did remove all **track_load++** from the code, and gives per-increment to  **track_load** before post when page scrolling. the code is,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
        var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
        var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

        $('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {
 //track_load++; <------ remove this from the code
}); //load first group

        $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-200)  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
            {

                if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
                {
                    loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                    $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                    //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
                    // add per-increment to ++track_load
                    $.post('autoload_process.php',{'group_no': ++track_load}, function(data){

                        $("#results").append(data); //append received data into the element

                        //hide loading image
                        $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                        //track_load++; <------ remove this from the code
                        loading = false; 

                    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                        alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                        $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                        loading = false;

                    });

                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```